# Data driven automation testing using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

The situation is, I am automating username and password fields and in my script i had hard coded the username and password fields. So can i get the CSV/excel file's cell content and pass it over the where ever the username and password fields are used. Like below my CSV/Excel file and it looks like below, so need javascript function to do it

```
username,password
XYZ,123
ABC,12345678
JAVASCRIPT,LSD
```

I am using CasperJs to automate the web page

Comment: *"selenium supports data driven framework"* No, there are frameworks that are built on top of some selenium language bindings or the webdriver wire protocol to run data driven testing. Selenium itself doesn't have that capability. The same is true for CasperJS. You can implement your own framework on top of CasperJS if you like, but this is *too broad* to make it a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. so is there any possible way to do it? I just need to use it for usernames and password fields

Comment: Yes, you can read a file, parse it and iterate over the username-password pairs to schedule multiple steps (`then*`).

Comment: can you just explain me how to do it? As i am begginer and totally new to this technology

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it specific with all your constraints. Where does the data come from? How is it organized?

Comment: Is there any solution for this? or should i hard code for the values